# Ansible when conditional with variable and item

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I'm having hard time trying to figure it out what I'm doing wrong with my Ansible playbook.

I've got a bunch of tasks, which define or not some variables according to context, depending of the result, some task will be ignored or not.

For this specific case, I check if a VlanID already exists, if it doesn't then I create one, and retrieve the new VlanID from the result.

Here is the playbook :

```
---
#Tasks for portGroup_add
- name: Get all portgroups in dvswitch vDS
  community.vmware.vmware_dvs_portgroup_find:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    dvswitch: "{{ vcenter_dvSwitch }}"
    validate_certs: False
  register: portGroup_infos
  when: (OLD_VLANID is not defined) or (OLD_VLANID|length < 1)

  #Get last VLAN ID for HDS client, and set VLANID + 1
- name: get portGroup_infos
  set_fact:
    VLANID: "{{ item.vlan_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ portGroup_infos.dvs_portgroups}}"
  when:
    - (portGroup_infos is defined) and (portGroup_infos|length > 0)
    - item.name | regex_search("\(HDS :\s*")
```

While everything is working pretty well for most of the tasks, this one fires the following error :

```
The conditional check 'item.name | regex_search("\(HDS :\s*")' failed. 
The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.name | regex_search("\(HDS :\s*")): 'item' is undefined
```

Which is pretty obvious, because the dict portGroup_infos, is not defined.

In order to get the new VlanID, I'm using a "when" conditionnal , which check if in the item, the value "(HDS :" , is present.

But I don't want the task to launch if the portGroup_infos variable defined above is not set, I though I'd should use nested "when", but can't succeed.

Ansible version : 2.10.7
python version : 3.7.3

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `- item.name is defined and item.name | regex_search("\(HDS :\s*")`?

Comment: unfortunately the same thing was happening, Vladimir's answer fixed the issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both tasks into a block, e.g.

```yaml
- block:
    - name: Get all portgroups in dvswitch vDS

      ...

    - name: get portGroup_infos

      ...

  when: OLD_VLANID|default('')|length == 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everything is working well now.